# .log parser (MySQL / Apache)

Tags: mysql, log-files

Is there any tool (GUI) to parse MySQL och Apache log files? to a more readable format?
Have Googled a lot, can't find anything to answer my need.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your definition of "more readable"?

Comment: For example being able to sort & filter witch part of the log file to be displayed, filtering UPDATE, SELECT. DELETE etc... from each other without having the need to work directly on the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own Apache log formate. Though it is not obvious what is readable (I find the combined log formate pretty good readable)

Most important is what information it is you want to get out of your logs.

For Apache the tool webalizer analizes the logs and shows statistics. It is maybe a bit rusty bit it does it's job

For MySQL you could try http://myprofi.sourceforge.net/ or google a bit around.